# PHP: assigning an empty object dynamically to stdClass

Tags: php, json, stdclass

Hi i'm exploring around & find something that leads me to an error.

my script is making a json format to a simpliest way to read and to code i found this.

```
$animal->dog = "dalmatian";
$animal->cat = "persian";

echo json_encode($animal);
```

this script leads me to an error of:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value

after I search in stackoverflow I found a solution using stdClass.

SOLUTION:

```
$animal = new stdClass;
```

this works and resolve the error but how about i have many OBJECTS on my script i gonna declare each objects on stdClass?

LIKE

```
$animals = new stdClass;
$mammals = new stdClass;
```

is there any way to get every empty OBJECT and declare dynamically to stdClass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help -

```
$animal = (object) array();
$animal->dog = "dalmatian";
$animal->cat = "persian";

echo json_encode($animal);
```

Or you can store them to array -

```
$animal['dog'] = "dalmatian";
$animal['cat'] = "persian";

echo json_encode($animal);
```

Storing them to array will work. And if you want it to be an object then simply cast it.

```
$animal = (object) $animal;
```

Comment: i see. so i gonna assign every empty object again? like

$animal = (object) array();
$mammal = (object) array():
....and so on

Comment: Why do you need them to be object? If you really need it then store them to array and after setting all cast them to object.

Comment: i tried using array but in my case putting them to be a object is more efficient than having them in array that will cause multi dimensional arrays